# Setting type to be equal to keys of an Object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I have an initial state object i.e.

```
interface IInitialState {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: string;
  prop4: Array<number>;
}

const INITIAL_STATE: IInitialState = {
  prop1: '',
  prop2: '',
  prop3: '',
  prop4: [],
};
```

Now I have declared another type as

```
type FieldType = 
 | 'prop1'
 | 'prop2'
 | 'prop3'
 | 'prop4'
```

Is there any elegant way to define FieldType such that it accepts only keys of INITIAL_STATE object instead of having me write it out as it's currently?

Comment: [keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator)?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    prop1: '',
    prop2: '',
    prop3: '',
    prop4: [],
}
type FieldType = keyof typeof INITIAL_STATE // gives "prop1" | "prop2" | "prop3" | "prop4"
```